# FindBy columnName when column name contains "Id"

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

In Grails, Gorm, I have this entity:

```
class MyEntity implements Serializable {

Long bankTransactionId

int version

BigDecimal someValue

static constraints = {
    bankTransactionId(nullable: false)
    version(nullable: true)
    someValue(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

Doing MyEntity.findByBankTransactionId(Long.valueOf("3")) throws this exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'this_.id' in 'field list'

I am suspecting the fact that my column has the name id in it. Could it be this?

How to fix it then ?

Thanks.

Comment: try renaming it to itemId sounds like element might be some reserverd word

Comment: Actually the real name is bankTransactionId.. just changed it to element.. 
updating the question..

Comment: well try alternatives see what happens in other situations a simple alternative would be `MyEntity.find{ elementId == 3L} `

Comment: I am using elements with somethingId all over my code base on grails 3.2.8 and it works fine. Perhaps you need to outline what version of grails you are using - have you tried other versions of grails to see if it is a bug ? Really hard for anyone to give you absolute answer. In short Long somethingId  is absolutely fine usually

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I am using 2.5.5..

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have provided here looks fine.  In particular, there are no restrictions about having the letters "id" in a column name.

Take a look at your generated MySQL table.  I'm guessing that the id column isn't there for some reason.  Maybe something prevented generating it due to some earlier error that you have now corrected, or you have your datasource set to "none" instead of "update" (or similar) and the whole table is missing!

If this is just a development environment with no real data (and no foreign key constraints), drop the whole MyEntity table and let it be automatically recreated.  If not, move to a different temporary datasource, let a new table be created, and compare the two.  If the new one still doesn't have an id column, you have something going wrong during your startup that is preventing your tables from being created correctly.  You could just add the column in manually, but if you don't figure out what happened to it in the first place, it will probably just happen again.

For reference, in my test environment, my MySQL table for "MyEntity" copied from your example looks like:

```
desc my_entity;

'id','bigint(20)','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'version','int(11)','YES','',NULL,''
'bank_transaction_id','bigint(20)','NO','',NULL,''
'some_value','decimal(19,2)','YES','',NULL,''
```